# Randomize embeds discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to randomize 6 simple embeds of a dice but for some reason it doesn't work and i don't know how to make it work.

```
embed1 = discord.Embed()
embed1.set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/28e8fc51f2e2945fd7cd6b3a158ab7115993a1be3328e656713f01107282c4cc.png')

embed2 = discord.Embed()
embed2.set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/a2daafe7bb4b6fd9aef54aa313d7e19b5beae28a2dbcba4d3dacc9be8b2ffcee.png')

embed3 = discord.Embed()
embed3.set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/04fd25da832cb85af325ab32e714642bef78c97a0858062bb0b15a168f1e185f.jpeg')

embed4 = discord.Embed()
embed4.set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/b26214af7789cf5bd239f862485e10910fe4cb167437338c12abdbb374f4f683.png')

embed5 = discord.Embed()
embed5.set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/64472c33b4a99025e133e9d063128e08b468abb58ab8b8d8fa3d8b57d7da52bc.png')

embed6 = discord.Embed()
embed6.set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/183014dc016ae2658314b25d8f2ad5a442aea04999b2457c66381a9e651c4c82.png')

embeds = [f'{embed1}', f'{embed2}', f'{embed3}', f'{embed4}', f'{embed5}', f'{embed6}']

@client.command()
async def dados(ctx): 
    await ctx.send(embed={random.choice(embeds)})

#This is what i tried, it says that the str doesn't have the to_dict attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes I made:

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

embeds = [
    discord.Embed().set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/28e8fc51f2e2945fd7cd6b3a158ab7115993a1be3328e656713f01107282c4cc.png'),
    discord.Embed().set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/a2daafe7bb4b6fd9aef54aa313d7e19b5beae28a2dbcba4d3dacc9be8b2ffcee.png'),
    discord.Embed().set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/04fd25da832cb85af325ab32e714642bef78c97a0858062bb0b15a168f1e185f.jpeg'),
    discord.Embed().set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/b26214af7789cf5bd239f862485e10910fe4cb167437338c12abdbb374f4f683.png'),
    discord.Embed().set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/64472c33b4a99025e133e9d063128e08b468abb58ab8b8d8fa3d8b57d7da52bc.png'),
    discord.Embed().set_image(url='https://cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/commands/images/551250166196207634/183014dc016ae2658314b25d8f2ad5a442aea04999b2457c66381a9e651c4c82.png')
]

@client.command()
async def dados(ctx):
    await ctx.send(embed=random.choice(embeds))

client.run('your_token')
```

1. I imported the necessary modules (discord, random, commands) at the
   beginning.
2. I created the list embeds with properly constructed discord.Embed
   instances directly in the list.
3. In the dados command, I directly pass the randomly chosen embed from
   the list to ctx.send(embed=...).